# Flutter http sending list value in the body in a post multipart request

Tags: flutter, http, dart, http-headers, multipart

I am trying to send a multipart post request to upload images and sending some other data in flutter with a body looks like this

```
bodyMap = {
  'type' : 'text',
  'content': [
     {
        'type': image'
        'identifier: '1234'
     }
   ]
};
```

However when I'm trying to add it to the request like this

```
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
request.fields.addAll(bodyMap);
```

it refuses to add it as it only accepts Map<String, String>

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) Package allows you to post a map of type Map<String,Dynamic> with multipart post request, for example:

```
var formData = FormData.fromMap({
  'name': 'wendux',
  'age': 25,
  'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile('./text.txt', filename: 'upload.txt'),
  'files': [
    await MultipartFile.fromFile('./text1.txt', filename: 'text1.txt'),
    await MultipartFile.fromFile('./text2.txt', filename: 'text2.txt'),
  ]
});
var response = await dio.post('/info', data: formData);
```